# Does anyone know where to get actual Cray PVP code?

Tags: assembly, emulation, cray

I want to write a emulator for one of the older Crays, but I've run into a stumbling block.  I can't seem to find any actual code for them.  (Which kind of makes sense I suppose, most of them would have been used for defense and the like..)  Does anyone know where I might find something?  Binaries or source, it's all good.  The thing I'd like the most is a binary of COS.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: If you don't have any code for a Cray, what do you plan to do with the emulator? Isn't it kind of pointless without code?

Comment: I want to understand the architecture really well just because it's such an important group of computers history-wise.  Having actual code to run gives me validation that my assumptions from the docs were correct.  (As I'm sure you know, even the best docs leave ambiguities; that's very often where the most interesting parts of an architecture lie).

Comment: The maker of Cray-1 clone found something but not online (it's a removable disk pack) -- http://www.chrisfenton.com/homebrew-cray-1a/

Answer (score 2):

The CAL manual is online :

http://docs.cray.com/cgi-bin/craydoc.cgi?mode=View;id=SR-3108_9.1;idx=books_search;this_sort=title;q=;type=books;title=CRAY%20Assembly%20Language%20%28CAL%29%20for%20Cray%20PVP%20Systems%20Reference%20Manual